# How to get Konva.TextPath width considering additional parameters

Tags: konvajs, konva

Good day, reader.

I am trying to create curved text with dynamic path using Konva, so I am transferring Konva.Text to Konva.TextPath, adding to Text attrs calculated path (code  sample is written in the end), although I can't get Konva.TextPath's right width taking into consideration additional parameters listed below. I tried this methods`

- `textNode.textwidth`
- `textNode.width()`
- `textNode.textWidth()`
- `textNode.getClientRect().width` // wrong size when curved

The most close to what I want is 3th option (it seems that it's same as 1st?).

Is there anyway to get width of Konva.TextPath considering also parameters like `

- font,
- font-size,
- letter-spacing,

I read documentation, looked through stackoverflow, but couldn't find any way. Is there something  I'm missing out ?

```
function redraw(originTextNode: Konva.Text | Konva.TextPath)
   const textWidth = textNode.textWidth();
   const calcedNewPath = calcNewPath({...other, textWidth })

   const textNode = Konva.TextPath({
     ...originTextNode.getAttrs(),
     data: calcedNewPath,
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you clary why exactly do you need a width? And what is "additional parameters" for you? letterSpacing?

Comment: Sorry, I updated question, parameters are listed. Width is used to calculate radius, which I use in svg path (using A command). If there is anything else to clarify, I'll be happy to, thanks

Comment: Is this any random path or can we scope it down to say rectangles or ellipses ?

Comment: No it's not random path, it's circle with 359 degree, radius depends on text width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `textPath.getTextWidth()` to get width of the text without `letterSpacing` adjustments. It will include `fontFamily` (if font is loaded) and `fontSize`. If you want to apply `letterSpacing` to that value you can do this:

```js
var fullWidth = textPath.getTextWidth() + (textPath.text().length - 1) * letterSpacing;
```

The actual length of the rendered text path can be still a bit different compared to the length of the path.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I will try this out!